# How do you control Eclipse's generated Bluetooth java files?

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, generated-code

I've got an Android project built under Eclipse-Indigo that works just fine.  I recently copied many of the files and rebuilt under Eclipse-Juno.  The app runs if you install it and/or run it from Eclipse, but if you try to generate an APK, you get:

Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: multiple dex file define Landroid/bluetooth/IBluetooth;

Comparing the directories shows that src/android.bluetooth/IBluetooth.aidl and IBluetoothCallback.aidl are identical, but gen/android.bluetooth exists in the working version but not the broken one. Replacing these files manually makes Eclipse whine, of course, so the question is:
how do I control how Eclipse generates those particular files from the AIDL inputs?

Alternatively, if somebody has an intelligent suggestion as to how to get rid of the stupid error, I'll take that instead :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to NOT install the Android Development Kit, which seems to have borked libraries.  Instead, install Eclipse for Java Developers, and install the Android SDK separately.  This allowed the correct libraries to appear, and didn't give the stupid errors about duplicate dex files.